# Google Maps change icon when I click one button

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I need to create an interactive map that change markers (my map have 3 markers) when an user click on an external button

For example the map is this when you open the site:

[image]

When you click button 1, change only the icon like in this photo

[image]

Can you help me with the javascript code? :)
This is my HTML code

```
<div id="mapMeteo"></div>
<br>
<button id="btn1">Bottone1</button> <button id="btn2">Bottone2</button> <button id="btn3">Bottone3</button>
```

This is the javascript code for google:

```
<script>
    function initialize() {
        //Marker personalizzato
        var imageMM = 'images/markerMM.png';
            imageMMM = 'images/markerMMM.png';
            imageMC = 'images/markerMC.png';

        //mappa Meteo
        var mapMeteo = document.getElementById('mapMeteo');
        var Latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(42.9254851, 13.8632125);
        var mapMOptions = {
            center: Latlng,
            zoom: 12,
            mapTypeControl: false,
            draggable: false,
            scaleControl: false,
            scrollwheel: false,
            navigationControl: false,
            streetViewControl: false,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
        var mapM = new google.maps.Map(mapMeteo, mapMOptions);

        //Marker 1
        var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(42.9547985, 13.958793),
            map: mapM,
            icon: imageMMM
        });

        var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(42.9222113, 13.9199294),
            map: mapM,
            icon: imageMM
        });

        var marker3 = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(42.8832739, 13.9438162),
            map: mapM,
            icon: imageMC
        });
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

and this is my jquery code but doesn't change the icon

`$("#btn1").click(function(){
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, 'click', function() {
        marker1.setIcon(imageMM);
        infowindow.open(mapM);
    });
});`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a dom listener and the `setIcon` method of the Marker class.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#methods_48

For example:

```
var btn1 = document.getElementById('btn1');

google.maps.event.addDomListener(btn1, 'click', function() {

    marker1.setIcon(imageMC);
});
```

<kbd>[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/mxz0tqn1/)</kbd>

Comment: I seen, but I've 5 markers and this code doesn't work with more than one marker